# How do I run a function on click?

Tags: javascript, web

Here's my code:

```
selectList = document.querySelectorAll("li.select");

selectList.addEventListener("click", function (){
selectList.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

When I just did the 'querySelectorAll' part, I used console.log and it worked. Showed me how many nodes I had.

I'm trying to add the class, open to the text whenever it's clicked. Nothing is working.

Please tell me what I did wrong.

The whole code is here: https://code.sololearn.com/WSH825hFGSz7/?ref=app

Comment: Add your HTML code too.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns multible elements `addEventListener` only works on a single element.

Comment: @RolandStarke Ok. What could I use that would work on all similar elements?

Comment: @ValaKhosravi ok.

Comment: @ValaKhosravi It can't enter. Let me put it somewhere and send you the link.

Comment: @ValaKhosravi , here. https://code.sololearn.com/WSH825hFGSz7/?ref=app

Comment: You would need to add a `for` loop and then add event listener. Better solution is however is to do event delegation. https://javascript.info/event-delegation.

Comment: Just read the answers from the dupe target.